# How to load a div when clicked on anchor tag using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am doing some experiment with the tab feature from bootstrap. In my code I want the content in div with id content 1 to be shown and content in second div should hide when the first anchor tag is clicked. same for anchor tag.

I want to achieve the same without using javascript and just with the help of bootstrap.

**HTML MARKUP:**

```
<a href="#content1" class="btn btn-default btnToClk" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="content1">
 Click to Load content1
</a>
<a href="#content2" class="btn btn-default btnToClk" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="content2">
 Click to Load content2
</a>

<div id="#content1">
  Content1 to be shown
</div>
<div id="#content2">
  Content2 to be shown
</div>
```

The code above does not seem to work. So, do I need to add some other stuffs. I think the the classes provided by bootstrap are just for styling. and if I guess It is not mandatory to follow the same format of ul and li as mentioned in bootstrap documentation. So, is data-toggle , a href and an id is enough to do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to achieve the same without using javascript and just with the
>   help of bootstrap.

Just to clarify, Bootstrap's `data-toggle=tab` is one of their jQuery plugins (see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). You need to include the associated js files (or bootstrap.js / bootstrap.min.js) and its dependencies (jQuery)

So Bootstrap is actually using javascript.

> I think the the classes provided by bootstrap are just for styling.

Not exactly, the classes are there to tell bootstrap that these sets of tabs belong together.

> and if I guess It is not mandatory to follow the same format of ul and
>   li as mentioned in bootstrap documentation.

Correct, Bootstrap's plugin code is not tied to ul, li and a. You need jus the following

1. elements with `data-toggle='tab'` and `href` to tell Bootstrap which tab each one links to
2. For the tabs, a wrapper with class tab-content (to tell Bootstrap that only one of the tabs within this should be shown at a time) and children with class tab and the id's indicated in the `href`.

If you set one of the tabs to active, that will the one shown by default. Otherwise you need to click a link to show a tab.

> So, is data-toggle , a href and an id is enough to do the job?

data-toggle, href, id **and tab-content and tab classes.**. Here is one set of minimal markup that replicates tab behaviour

```
<a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
<a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
<a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>
<a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">a</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">b</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">c</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">d</div>
</div>
```

You could replace the `a` with something else (wouldn't be valid HTML though) and the div too.